# Is product of a monoidal category $C$ with itself a part of $C$?

Tags: category-theory

If $C$ is a monoidal category, where $⊗ : C \times C \to C$, is $C \times C$ considered part of the category $C$ or is it a separate category (a product category)?

Comment: It's a separate category. What would it mean for it to "be part of" C? Similarly, the binary operation of a group $G$ is a map $G \times G\to G$, but in no sense is $G \times G$ a "part of" $G$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is not part of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I guess my problem was with the definition:  monoidal category (or tensor category) is a category equipped with a bifunctor ⊗:C×C→C. Does this definition imply that C x C exists?

Comment: Yes of course the product is assumed to exist, because it exists. The answer by @QuantumSpace states what it is, but that should be obvious to you if you're studying this stuff with any success.

Comment: Thank you for your replies.  I now feel more comfortable accepting and understanding the implicit assumptions in Wikipedia's definition of a monoidal category.  Regards, DMJ.

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 1):

Given categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{}$, we can form a new category $\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{D}$, as follows:

The objects are pairs $(C,D)$ where $C$ is an object in $\mathcal{C}$ and $D$ is an object in $\mathcal{D}$.

The morphisms are defined by
$$\operatorname{Hom}((C_1,D_1),(C_2, D_2))=\operatorname{Hom}(C_1, D_1)\times \operatorname{Hom}(C_2, D_2)$$
and are composed in each component individually.

In your definition, $\mathcal{D}=\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. . .I don't quite understand the terminology you are using with the Hom definitions, but I'll continue to work on it.

Comment: The terminology is completely standard. The Hom-sets are the sets of (homo)morphisms between objects. I'm also a little baffled that you don't know what a product category is but that you are studying tensor categories.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your understanding of category theory.  Not being a mathematician, I often go about studying the subject in unusual ways.

Comment: @DMJ Yes, different people tend to have different learning styles. If you can be more specific what you don't understand about my answer, I can try to clarify it for you. Please also clarify what definition of category you are using.

Comment: I appreciate your willingness to help further, but I think I'm good to go.  You may see me back on StackExchange with other queries.  Regards.